# Replace a value if this value is present in a txt file

Tags: unix, replace, txt

Goodmorning everyone, I have a `data.ped` file made up of thousands of columns and hundreds of lines. The first 6 columns and the first 4 lines of the file look like this:

```
186 A_Han-4.DG 0 0 1 1
187 A_Mbuti-5.DG 0 0 1 1
188 A_Karitiana-4.DG 0 0 1 1
191 A_French-4.DG 0 0 1 1
```

And I have a `ids.txt` file that looks like this:

```
186 Ignore_Han(discovery).DG
187 Ignore_Mbuti(discovery).DG
188 Ignore_Karitiana(discovery).DG
189 Ignore_Yoruba(discovery).DG
190 Ignore_Sardinian(discovery).DG
191 Ignore_French(discovery).DG
192 Dinka.DG
193 Dai.DG
```

What I need is to replace (in unix) the value in the first column of the `data.ped` file with the value in the second column of the `ids.txt` that is in the same line of the value that is going to be replaced from the `data.ped` file. For example, I want to replace the "186" value from the `data.ped` first column with the "Ignore_Han(discovery).DG" value from the `ids.txt` second column (and this because in the first column of the same line of this value there is "186") So the `output.ped` file must look like this:

```
Ignore_Han(discovery).DG A_Han-4.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_Mbuti(discovery).DG A_Mbuti-5.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_Karitiana(discovery).DG A_Karitiana-4.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_French(discovery).DG A_French-4.DG 0 0 1 1
```

The values of the first column of the data.ped file are a subset of the values present in the first column of the ids.txt file. So there is always match.

---

**Edit:**

I've tried with this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]; print}' ids.txt data.ped
```

but when I check the result with:

```
cut -f 1-6 -d " " output.ped
```

I get this strange output:

```
A_Han-4.DG 0 0 1 1y).DG
A_Mbuti-5.DG 0 0 1 1y).DG
A_Karitiana-4.DG 0 0 1 1y).DG
A_French-4.DG 0 0 1 1y).DG
```

while if I use this command:

```
cut -f 1-6 -d " " output.ped | less
```

I get this:

```
Ignore_Han(discovery).DG^M A_Han-4.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_Mbuti(discovery).DG^M A_Mbuti-5.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_Karitiana(discovery).DG^M A_Karitiana-4.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_French(discovery).DG^M A_French-4.DG 0 0 1 1
```

and I can't figure out why there is that ^M in every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]} 1' ids.txt data.ped
```

output:

```
Ignore_Han(discovery).DG A_Han-4.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_Mbuti(discovery).DG A_Mbuti-5.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_Karitiana(discovery).DG A_Karitiana-4.DG 0 0 1 1
Ignore_French(discovery).DG A_French-4.DG 0 0 1 1
```

This is a classic awk task with various modifications according to your requirements. Here we replaced the first field of `data.ped` only if we have found its value in the `ids.txt`, else we print the line unchanged. If you would like to remove lines that don't match:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]; print}' ids.txt data.ped
```

There is no need for the input files to be sorted and the order of the second file is preserved.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you have `Ctrl-M` characters in your inputs, remove them first with

```
cat file | tr -d '^M' > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

for any `file` you use. In general, I suggest running `dos2unix` for any text files that could contain characters like `^M` or `\r`, usually coming from dos/windows editing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` command to join two files

```
join ids.txt data.ped > temp
```

You can use `cut` command to remove the first column like:

```
cut -d " " -f 2- temp > output.ped
```